# Conditional testing in cypress

Tags: cypress

I have a button that may or may not be disabled via a switch next to it. I know it's state, when the test gets to it, but I feel like I should be checking it anyway and switching it if it isn't in the state I want.

How can I write a conditional for this in a cypress test?

```
if (testSubject.getButton().is("disabled) {
  // do stuff
} else {
  // do other stuff
}
```

Comment: That may be a good scenario for 2 different tests. One to test the disabled state and one to test the enabled state. Here is Cypress's take on conditional testing https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/conditional-testing#Definition

Comment: Yeah, I have tests for those two states, but  I also need to have a test to click the button if it's enabled.

Comment: Can you create a test that ensures the button is enabled? Then you don't need to worry about checking what state it is in.

Comment: Please add the HTML of your button when its in the disabled state.

Answer (score 0):

The general pattern for that is to use jQuery in your if statement,

```js
cy.get('my-button')
  .then($button => {
    if ($button.is(':enabled')) {
      cy.wrap($button).click()
    }
  })
```

Be aware that using conditional testing like this can mask a regression in the app that allows a bug to slip through. It's ok if you have other tests covering it.